# How are XCode Storyboards compiled?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I'm learning iOS development and I was wondering how Storyboards actually work when the app is running.
While the editable `.storyboard` is just an xml file, the compiled `.storyboardc` file in the application bundle seems to be a package containing many `.nib` files.
How do these nib files work at runtime? What are they exactly? How is data encoded and extracted?

Comment: This is not really important, but .nib files are roughly object graph serialization in either XML or Apple property list. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder or https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html